# PHP - Using empty interfaces to determine logic

Tags: php, oop, interface

There are a few places where I've executed logic based on what interfaces a class implements - is there any reason that this may or may not be wrong? (It feels dirty)

The reasoning behind doing this was so you don't have to add any class properties or methods to determine these things, basically in the class definition you can spell out explicitly what it could / could not do.

One use case is ajax calls, some require you to be logged in and some don't:

```
class ajax_ads extends ajax_controller implements no_login {

}
```

Also, there are no methods in the interface, it is used soley for this purpose.

```
interface no_login {}
```

Then in the base controller:

```
$controller = controller::factory()
if( !($controller instanceof no_login) && !$controller->LoggedIn()){
    return $controller->redirect(/*login page*/); 
}
```

It seems lightweight and simple to use instance_of and it works fine, but again it feels like I'm totally abusing the purpose of the interface.

So I ask, is using an interface to determine logic a bad idea, bad oop, or 'okay'?

Comment: My first instinct is to say this is wrong, but I'll need a bit of time to think of a good reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you need an `if` or a `switch` to determine the state an object should be, it's usually a good sign you are in need of **polymorphism**.

In your case, there should be one **abstract** class: `Ajax_Ads`, and two extending classes: `No_Login_Ajax_Ads extends Ajax_Ads`, and `Login_Ajax_Ads extends Ajax_Ads`. And you instantiate the one you require based on the state of the program, this could be done with a **factory**.

For more information, watch the following lecture: **[The Clean Code Talks -- Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)**

Comment: ah yes, that was [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867765/php-using-empty-interfaces-to-determine-logic#comment17418530_12867765)

Comment: That makes sense. What if I created an intermediary class that determined the login property? ajax_controller -> ajax_no_login -> ajax_ads or ajax_controller -> ajax_login -> ajax_ads. This way I can reuse amongst all my ajax controllers. (Noting that most are always all login or all no login)

Comment: @Aknosis: Watch this lecture for more details. A real eye opener (I recommend all of this guy's videos regarding OOP). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any downside, but it feels like a mis-use of the interface syntax. Why not implement a simple method in ajax_ads:

```
class ajax_ads
{
    ...
    public function requiresLogin() { return false; }
}
```

And then replace

```
if ($controller instanceof no_login) ...
```

by

```
if (!$controller->requiresLogin()) ...
```

This approach could be shortened to almost the same brevity with a [trait](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is from 2012. Laravel uses the empty interface pattern today so I would say it is OK.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Queue;

interface ShouldQueue
{
    //
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Queue/ShouldQueue.php

```
protected function sendMailable(MailableContract $mailable)
{
    return $mailable instanceof ShouldQueue
                    ? $mailable->mailer($this->name)->queue($this->queue)
                    : $mailable->mailer($this->name)->send($this);
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L300 (Lines 300-305)

Comment: I'm not sure Laravel doing that means it's best practice.